# Using old version of Cygwin

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I am trying to use the old version of 32 bit cygwin (1.7.22 - 1.7.32) which uses GCC 4.7.3 version.

Just found one (cygwin 1.7.25) but during the standard installation (running with setup-x86.exe) it shows the following errors:

> The current ini file is from a newer version of setup.exe. If you have
>   any trouble installing, please download a fresh version from "cygwin
>   official page"

Is that old version not supported anymore and I can not chose right address from where it can download and install the needed packages?

Thanks,
Arsen

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a good answer. Normally what you see in the installer is what you have access to.

When you load your `setup-x86.exe`, get to the packages (ignore the warning), and see if you can select the version of Cygwin you need (use the search box to narrow it down). On mine I can only get a few revisions and nothing as old as you need. That being said, I do have the latest installer and can't test this for you.

Comment: Thank you for the response. After ignoring the warning I am getting several errors which are actually stopped me.

Comment: You may be better off installing a newer version and finding a gcc of appropriate version to build

Comment: I have already moved to the latest available version and trying to compile what I need with the newer gcc version because it seems I would lost lots of time without essential progress there.
Thanks for responding !